# Substitute variables of a template body email from database by specific information in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, email-templates, cakeemail

Imagine this scenario, I have a table called "message_templates" with the following structure:-

```
id
subject
body
```

where the **body** value is:-

```
<p>ID: ${PROJECT_ID} </p>
<p>Project's Title: ${PROJECT_TITLE} </p>
```

What is the best way to substitute theses variables in CakePHP - I know it, CakeEmail has a Configuration parameter called "template" but its not the case, because my template(**body column**) comes from database. Maybe use `preg_replace`  or `sprintf` before send?

Somebody could help me?

Comment: preg_replace / str_replace is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and provide an array of tokens and an array of substitutions:-

```
$body = str_replace(
    [
        '${PROJECT_ID}',
        '${PROJECT_TITLE}'
    ], 
    [
        '1',
        'Foo bar'
    ],
    $data['MessageTemplate']['body']
);
```

You can then pass `$body` to CakeEmail and send the email as normal.

Comment: Ok. I will try. But sometimes i will not have all tokens. I need to  check if token is present on body message  or str_replace dont care about it?

Comment: If the token isn't present in the body message it will just skip over it with no problem. I use an approach much like this for a site I've been developing to allow the client to be able to edit the content of emails sent by the system with tokens for customer details. It works great.